# PHP iterating through a count shows incorrect sequence

Tags: php, wordpress, iteration

This is for a wordpress project but is more PHP really. I'm executing a query to bring back a max of 12 posts. Each set of three posts is wrapped in a div entitled `jobsN`. Each post (item) within that div comes back as `item1`, `item2` and `item3`.

The `item1` class works just fine but the `jobs` class doesn't come back as 1-2-3-4. It comes back as 1-0-0-0. I can't work out what is going wrong with my count.

As you can see from the HTML below, there is something off with the jobs count. This part is handled here:

```
    <?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; ?><div class="jobs
<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php }; ?>
```

Here is the full query:

```
<?php 
            query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'custom_job',
                'showposts' => 12 
            ) );  
        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ): $contcount = 0; $count = 0;?>
        <?php $contcount++; ?>
        <div class="jobs<?php echo $contcount; ?>">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++;?>
            <div class="item-<?php echo $count ?>">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Learn more</a> -->
            </div>
            <?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php }; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the HTML I get back:

```
<div class="jobs1">
        <div class="item-1">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-3">
            content
        </div>
</div>
<div class="jobs0">
        <div class="item-1">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-3">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="jobs0">
        <div class="item-1">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="item-3">
            content
        </div>
</div>
<div class="jobs0">
        <div class="item-1">
            content
        </div>
</div
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts`. It is unreliable, breaks the main query and outright fails in most situation when it comes to pagination. Rather use `WP_Query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
<?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php }; ?>
```

If $count = 3 it means you will desplay a new jobs div but you also make $count = 0 then you are echoing it as 0.

Transform this line to:

```
<?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; $countcount++; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $countcount; ?>"><?php }; ?>
```

Comment: This works although the variable is contcount, not countcount. So once I changed that it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

use this line

`<?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; $contcount++; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $contcount; ?>"><?php }; ?>`

instead of

`<?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php }; ?>`

Solution :

I have updated the `$contcount++` when `$count==3` and use in echo class `jobs<?php echo $contcount`

Comment: If you increase $contcount before output it, you're going to get 3 in the second block instead of 2

Comment: first time it is used outside the while 2 will be use next see above .i have updated it in when it has to be echo see once againa

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong counter in your PHP:

Your code has this line:

```
<?php if ($count == 3) {?></div><?php $count = 0; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php }; ?>
```

And it should be

```
<?php if ($count == 3) { ?></div><?php $count = 0; $contcount++; ?><div class="jobs<?php echo $contcount; ?>"><?php }; ?>
```

Because `$count` stores the item, and `$contcount` stores the block of items

Comment: see once again question value of 1 of $contcount is used outside the while loop you code will put 1-1 two times in starting

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the closing } on this line.

Comment: Solved, I forgot  to add ';' at the end of $countcount. Check the corrected code line

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, not 100% sure it will work

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'custom_job',
        'showposts' => 12 
    ) );  
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ): $contcount = 0; $count = 0;?>
<?php $contcount++; ?>
    <div class="jobs<?php echo $contcount; ?>">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++;?>
            <div class="item-<?php echo $count ?>">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Learn more</a>
            </div>
            <?php if ($count == 3): ?>
                <?php $count = 0; $countcount++;?>
                <div class="jobs<?php echo $contcount; ?>"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: Edited the possible error.

Comment: It errors at the first "endif" syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)